# The word "little" inferring the meaning of something important, big or critical

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-in-context

I may have made it up but it seems to me that the word **little** on some occasions infers the opposite of its intended meaning in certain contexts:

- Those guys are going to pay for what they've done. We'll pay them a little visit tonight.
- Honey, the little problem with you is that you don't want to try to understand people.
- We've got a little problem here and I'm not sure we're going anywhere any sooner.

Does it depend on the context or the reader's understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your examples, *little* is being used to understate the importance of the situation.

In the case of "little visit", the visit is likely to have a quite negative outcome. Not your average "visit".

In the case of "little problem", the problem is likely to be more involved than what "little" implies.

*paying a little visit* is idiomatic in situations involving criminal elements exacting some kind of "repayment" or "coercion" on some poor soul(s).

Answer (score 1):

That is irony, the rhetorical device of saying one thing while intending the contrary to be understood. Irony is not something peculiar to the word "little." Nor I suspect is it peculiar to English.

Comment: So this doesn't have to do with the word "**little**"?

Comment: I, at first, thought "litotes", but it's not; it's "irony" as Jeff Morrow has stated above and it is a play on the word "little".

Comment: @Sovereign No, it's not about "little." Any word with substantive meaning can be used ironically. "Great" in American speech is frequently used to mean " not great." I must admit that English is hard enough without rhetorical tricks, but there is a whole basket full of them employed both in serious writing and in casual speech.